# How to insert a chart with data non-contiguous in Excel using API office.js?

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, office365, office-js

I know is it possible with Excel doing something like this :

```
'---------------------
Set a1 = Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(20, 1))
Set a2 = Range(Cells(10, 8), Cells(20, 8))
u = Union(a1, a2).Address
'-------------
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets('Feuil1').Range(u), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

But Is it possible with the office.js API ?

Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to varying degrees of support for creating such charts on Excel desktop vs. Online vs. iOS vs. Mac, the APIs currently do not expose the ability to bind to a non-contiguous range. If you have noncontiguous data, your best bet would be to copy it to another sheet (which you can hide if you want) in a contiguous fashion, in the order in which you want the data displayed.  And then create a chart off of that (just like in regular Excel, the chart can be on a different sheet than its data range).

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. 
I thought of this solution but wish to avoid it :-(